# Using Shared preferences to save a string on a button click

Tags: java, android, sdk, sharedpreferences

So currently I have:

```
public void SaveText(View view) {
    String saved = text.getText().toString();
    // TODO
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addedfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

How do you save the 'Text' string and save it into shared preferences, without overwriting previous saved strings.

(Note: I've tried using arrays and array lists but I just end up with one result and overwriting it rather than adding to the previously saved strings)

I'm pretty new to this so please don't skip any steps regardless of how insignificant they may seem.

Comment: Shared preferences is a map, so 1 key = 1 value. I think you should consider using a database table if you wanted to store lists.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

while saving

```
   public void SaveText(View view) {
       String saved = text.getText().toString();
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
       editor.put("value",saved);
       editor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addedfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

while retriving

```
String value=prefs.getString("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the content which is already stored in your SharedPreferences, append the new value and finally write back to SharedPreferences.